# Determining case of a Bulk API *query* Failure

Tags: bulk-api, bulk-api-v2

For a particular query:

- I am initiating a query via the Bulk API v2 at `/services/data/v47.0/jobs/query`.
- I use the job id to query the status via `/services/data/v47.0/jobs/query/jobId`, repeatedly once every 15 seconds until I get a status indicating completion.
- Initially the status is *InProgress*, eventually after 2-3 minutes, the status changes to *Failed*.

Is there a mechanism to determine the reason for the failure? I saw an API call for insert/upsert/create/delete operations, but not for queries and not in the response of the [query job status](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/query_get_one_job.htm) API call.